# How to update child component is a state of useReducer when parent rerender

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer, rerender

Situation:

1. I have a parent component called `TestReducerScreen`
2. Inside parent render, I change the body by use useReducer. State of reducer is a child component instead of variable. Child component I want it's a function render html inside parent component.
3. Open google, click move to renderBox3. In renderBox3 have a input make change state of parent. See my image!

Problems:

- State of parent change and app parent rerender. But in screen interface component renderBox3 not rerender.

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from 'react';

export default function TestReducerScreen() {
    console.log('App rerendered!');
    const [input, setInput] = useState('Hi all');

    const defaultBoxRender = () => {    //=> state : mặc định/ban đầu
        console.log('defaultboxRender render');
        return <div id="defaultBoxRender">
            <p>This is default BoxRender</p>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch("SHOW_ME_renderBox2")}>Change to renderBox2</button>
        </div>
    }

    const renderBox2 = () => {
        console.log('renderBox2 render');
        return <div id='renderBox2'>
            <p>This is renderBox2</p>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch("SHOW_ME_renderBox3")}>Change to renderBox3</button>
        </div>;
    }

    const renderBox3 = () => {
        console.log('renderBox3 render');
        return <div id='renderBox3'>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input} placeholder="typeing somethings...." />
            <p>This is renderBox3 ; vl = {input}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setInput("Inside me")}>Change input values</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch("SHOW_ME_defaultBoxRender")}>Change to defaultBoxRender</button>
        </div>;
    }

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        console.log('state = ', state);
        switch (action) {
            case 'SHOW_ME_defaultBoxRender':
                return defaultBoxRender();
            case 'SHOW_ME_renderBox2':
                return renderBox2();
            case 'SHOW_ME_renderBox3':
                return renderBox3();
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    const [boxRender, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultBoxRender());

    return (
        <div id='Container'>
            {boxRender}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Expecting:

- Change state of parent in child component make current state update
- Sorry I'm not good at English. And if there have a same question

Comment: Why don't you include the code? It's so hard to copy-paste from an image.

Comment: oh sorry, i don't know that, i'll pastebin